# Find group and sorting data in laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I have two tables, one is products and the other is varients.
In product table I store product basic data such as name, image, brand, etc. In varients table I store variants of product such as 1kg, 2kg, 5kg, etc

**varients Table**

| id | product_id | varientName | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2kg | 100 |
| 2 | 1 | 1kg | 50 |
| 3 | 1 | 5kg | 480 |
| 4 | 2 | 250g | 25 |
| 5 | 2 | 100g | 10 |
| 6 | 2 | 500g | 50 |

**products Table**

| id | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | rice |
| 2 | tea |

I want to fetch data from both table such as - one product variant which one has lowest price.

I try this:

```
$bestSellingProduct = DB::table('products')
       ->join('varients', 'products.id', '=', 'varients.product_id')   
        ->select('products.product_id','products.name',,'varients.varientName','varients.id','varients.price')       
        ->orderBy('varients.varientPrice','ASC')
        ->groupby('products.id')
        ->get();
```

I want to fetch products and their variants, such as rice 1kg (50) and tea 100g (50).

Comment: Do you have all the relationships written? I want to give you the Eloquent Query.

Answer (score 4):

Using eloquent if you want to get product information based on minimun price then can you please try below query.

```
 $variantsData = DB::table('varients as v')
    ->select('v.product_id', 'v.varientName', 'v.price')
    ->join(DB::raw('(SELECT product_id, MIN(price) AS minPrice
                   FROM varients
                   GROUP BY product_id) as minPriceProduct'), function ($join) {
                       $join->on('v.product_id', '=', 'minPriceProduct.product_id')
                            ->on('v.price', '=', 'minPriceProduct.minPrice');
                   })
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eloquent like this.

```
$bestSellingProducts = DB::table('products')
->join('varients', 'products.id', '=', 'varients.product_id')   
->select('products.id', 'products.Name', DB::raw('MIN(varients.varientName) as min_varientName'), DB::raw('MIN(varients.id) as variant_id'), DB::raw('MIN(varients.price) as min_price'))
->orderBy('min_price', 'ASC')
->groupBy('products.id', 'products.Name')
->get();
```

OUTPUT:

```
id Name min_varientName variant_id min_price
2 tea 100g 4 10
1 rice 1kg 1 50
```

MySQl Query:

```
select `products`.`id`, `products`.`Name`, MIN(varients.varientName) as min_varientName, MIN(varients.id) as variant_id, MIN(varients.price) as min_price from `products` inner join `varients` on `products`.`id` = `varients`.`product_id` group by `products`.`id`, `products`.`Name` order by `min_price` asc
```

Answer (score 0):

Basic SQL for finding minimum value and also other columns of the min value record can be achieved using `window` function:

```
SELECT T.ID, T.NAME, T.VARIENTNAME, T.PRICE 
FROM
(SELECT P.ID, P.NAME, V.VARIENTNAME, V.PRICE,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.ID ORDER BY V.PRICE) RN
FROM PRODUCTS P 
     JOIN VARIENTS V ON P.ID = V.PRODUCT_ID) T
WHERE T.RN = 1
```

Comment: If it is a basic SQL, is this question a duplicate? Should it be closed as such instead of answering? I think this asker is seeking a Laravel-style query builder solution.